# REST API - How to implement multiple methods with same name but different accepted parameters type

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, webapi

Let's say I want to implement a User API Controller. Client needs to get users by integer ID, so I create a method `GET - /api/User/{id:int}`.

Then for some reason I want to implement getting a user by its name. The most obvious solution is to create `GET - /api/User/{name:string}` but this method will be conflicting with the previous one. Naming a method `/api/UserByName/{name:string}` breaks REST entity rules.

How can I deal with this problem without breaking REST rules?

Update: I just wrote the following code to create multiple routes:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] int id)
{
    return Ok();
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] string name)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

This code cannot be translated by swagger and produces an error:

> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Conflicting method/path combination "GET WeatherForecast" for actions - WebApiSkeleton.API.Contro
> llers.WeatherForecastController.Get (WebApiSkeleton.API),WebApiSkeleton.API.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get (WebApiSkeleton.API). Actions require a
> unique method/path combination for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0. Use ConflictingActionsResolver as a workaround

Calling a method raises another exception:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:
> WebApiSkeleton.API.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get (WebApiSkeleton.API)
> WebApiSkeleton.API.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get (WebApiSkeleton.API)

Comment: I don't see that working. A valid number is also a valid string. So on what basis the route should be evaluated to get to the correct endpoint? You might try to just do the string endpoint. And then if its also a valid number treat it as the id. So do the distinction in code not by route.

Comment: On the c# side of things it should work without a problem, after all they are two different method with two different types...

Comment: I would take {id_name:string} then parse it inside as id 1) if id is always int and 2)you have rules for username not to have only numbers

Comment: I would add is a [FromQuery] on the route

Comment: For example have a look at this microsoft graph api (get a user) endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http. You can pass either a user id or a upn (email), so they probably distinguish in the backend on what to do. That approach seems fine to me.

Comment: You might rather want to look at UriParameter to get something more telling like `/api/User?id=1` or `/api/User?name=ralf`

Comment: updated the body of the question with code and exceptions

Comment: as for the Ralf's answer I don't think this is gonna work as user might be having a numeric name for some reason. How do I treat it this way?

Comment: Then we are at UriParameter as you can do then  `/api/User?id=1` vs. `/api/User?name=1`. You get an explicit distinction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did mean by using [FromQuery] is this.
It would required for you to have a class with id and name

```
public class UserFilter
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then have the route like this

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] UserFilter filter)
{
    if (filter.Id.HasValue)
    {
        // Search by id
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Name))
    {
        // Searh by name
    }
    return BadRequest();
}
```

Comment: This will also allow for a query with no parameters at all.

Comment: I just copy past from is code
I can just replace that Ok(); with BadRequest(); since on that route he wants to get the user by Id or by Name, if none is provided a BadRequest would return.
But this is the only way I see it, for this to work, and the swagger would not complain about it

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net core routing uses a [precedence in selecting routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#url-matching), usually from more specific to generic. Hence, if you have two routes one with {id:int} and the other one without any qualifier or :alpha qualifier, then if you send an int you the {id:int} will be hit otherwise, the other more generic route will be hit. This means that these two routes can co-exist and will do what you want to do:

```
[HttpGet("something/{id:int}")]
public IActionResult Get1(int id)
{
    return Ok();
}

[HttpGet("something/{id}")]
public IActionResult Get2(string id)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

You can test to call these two enpoints using postman or any http client.
The error you are having is probably related to swagger not able to generate documentation, which says something like this :
`Conflicting method/path combination`
That has nothing to do with asp.net core but swagger.

What you can do is ignore the one that takes {id:int} from swagger, since it's the less generic. You can use : `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` for that.
Once you do that, if you open swagger you will see a single endpoint but if you try it out with an int you will hit the {id:int} endpoint, otherwise you will hit the {id} endpoint.

Comment: Does not help directly here where the same value might have 2 different meanings but its good to know that there is a chance for resolving that conflict by type for somewhat similar problems.

Comment: @Ralf I agree, but that can be documented in the swagger as a good compromise.